# В процессе работы ломается функция умножения матриц

Tags: c++

Функция перемножения:

```
std::vector< std::vector<double> > mult_mat(std::vector< std::vector<double> > a, std::vector< std::vector<double> > b) {
    std::vector< std::vector<double> > res(a.size(), std::vector<double>(b[0].size(), 0));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < res.size(); ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < res.size(); ++j) {
            for (size_t q = 0; q < a[i].size(); ++q) {
                if (a[i].size() != b.size()) exit(10);
                res[i][j] += a[i][q] * b[q][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Вызываю следующим образом:

```
std::vector< std::vector<double> > res;
...
res = mult_mat(basis, {{x}, {y}, {z}});
```

С чем может быть связана эта проблема?

Comment: 1)Функция вываливается не по exit. Т.к выдаёт принудительное завершение процесса
2)Basis - вектор постоянный 3х3

Comment: Поставьте ручную проверку границ выхода за пределы массива. В большинстве случаев это случается при выходе переменных за пределы массива.

Answer (score 2):

У вас j от 0 до 2. При этом res и b оба 3*1.

Соответственно в Вашей строке

`res[i][j] += a[i][q] * b[q][j];`

ошибка что `res[i][j]`, что `b[q][j]`